# How can I condition GraphQL mutation based on exists?

Tags: graphql, schema, mutation, graphql-playground

I am creating schemas in GraphQl and testing these in Playground. These seem to work fine in being able to create Club, User and Team, yet I only want to be able to create a team if a club exists and can therefore connect to the club. At the moment I can create a team without a club existing, which of course shouldn't happen. On create Team Mutation, I also want to stop any club being created, the club must exist prior to any mutation on a Team.

Here is what I have at the moment for my schemas

```
type Club {
 id: ID! @unique
 name: String! @unique
 team: [Team!]! @relation(name: "TeamToClub", onDelete: CASCADE)
 admin: User! @relation(name: "UserToClub", onDelete: SET_NULL)
 }

type User {
  id: ID! @unique
  name: String!
  team: [Team!]! @relation(name: "TeamToUser", onDelete: SET_NULL)
  club: [Club!]! @relation(name: "UserToClub", onDelete: SET_NULL)
}

type Team {
 id: ID! @unique
 name: String!
 club: Club! @relation(name: "TeamToClub", onDelete: SET_NULL)
 creator: User! @relation(name: "TeamToUser", onDelete: SET_NULL)
 coach:[Coach!]! @relation(name: "CoachToTeam", onDelete: SET_NULL)
}
```

Here are my mutations for creating a user

```
mutation {
  createUser(
    data:{
      name:"Jack Jones",
      email:"jack@example.com"
    }
  ){
    id
    name
  }
}
```

and creating a team..

```
mutation {
  createTeam(
    data:{
      title:"Barcelona FC"
      agegroup:"Under 12s",
      published: false,
      coachcreator:{
        connect:{
          id:"cka8qkd5h02dj0815m3odzh5s"
        }
      }
    }
  ){
    id
    title
    agegroup
    published
    coachcreator {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

both of which work without connecting to a club.

Could anybody provide a possible solution to ensure a condition is in place to say a team can only be created when a club already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Strange mutations - looks like they are completely not related to types.

Usually create mutation returns created type, f.e. `createUser` returns `User` ... and mutation argument - input type (`UserInput`) - with almost the same shape as returned type (without `id`).

The simplest method to ensure that `createTeam` has proper (existing) club relation is to define club as required argument of mutation.